# Wrong queryString when building navigation plan in aurelia-router

Tags: aurelia

We're using *aurelia-open-id-connect* in our project and after successful login the redirect is removing the querystring from the url. I've debugged my way through the *aurelia-router* and I think I found something. Should'nt the queryString in **redirectInstruction** be used there?

```
export const buildRedirectPlan = (instruction: NavigationInstruction) => {
  const config = instruction.config;
  const router = instruction.router;
  return router
    ._createNavigationInstruction(config.redirect)
    .then(redirectInstruction => {

      const params: Record<string, any> = {};
      const originalInstructionParams = instruction.params;
      const redirectInstructionParams = redirectInstruction.params;

      for (let key in redirectInstructionParams) {
        // If the param on the redirect points to another param, e.g. { route: first/:this, redirect: second/:this }
        let val = redirectInstructionParams[key];
        if (typeof val === 'string' && val[0] === ':') {
          val = val.slice(1);
          // And if that param is found on the original instruction then use it
          if (val in originalInstructionParams) {
            params[key] = originalInstructionParams[val];
          }
        } else {
          params[key] = redirectInstructionParams[key];
        }
      }
      let redirectLocation = router.generate(redirectInstruction.config, params, instruction.options);

      // Special handling for child routes
      for (let key in originalInstructionParams) {
        redirectLocation = redirectLocation.replace(`:${key}`, originalInstructionParams[key]);
      }

      let queryString = instruction.queryString; 
      // use redirectInstruction.queryString instead?
      if (queryString) {
        redirectLocation += '?' + queryString;
      }

      return Promise.resolve(new Redirect(redirectLocation));
    });
};
```

[image: I get this incorrect redirect location]

Comment: This is an issue with latest history-browser module, which is used by aurelia-router to handle the fragment. Please make sure you use 1.3.1: `npm i aurelia-history-browser@1.3.1` and wait for incoming release. Sorry for this

Comment: @bigopon I'm using version 1.3.1 of aurelia-history-browser now, still same issue.

Comment: I think you are correct. Sorry for not ready the question carefully. It seems to be wrong for awhile, per v1.6.3 https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/cfcc40c9cdbf0cc87cbd71c45cae0076283a8d9e/src/navigation-plan.js#L49

Will fix soon.

Comment: I'm handling tests for this scenario, could you help create an issue and give at least some pseudo code to demonstrate this and reproduction?

Comment: @bigopon I have opened an issue now, https://github.com/aurelia/router/issues/639.